# Aligning a custom CSS button between two elements in a container

Tags: html, css

I am working on a CSS file to design Cards, similar to Material Design Cards. 
I have also designed a button similar to a FAB. I wish to combine these two elements, so the card has the FAB on the right side between the image and the card content, but I am not sure how to go about doing this.

Here is the current CSS design:
[image]

CSS Code:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Noto+Serif');

body {
    background: #DDD;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    width: 500px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.card p {
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    padding: 2px 16px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.card img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.card p.title {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20pt;
    padding: 2px 16px;
}

.bordered {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.rounded {
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.fab {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 11px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18), 
                0px 4px 12px -7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    font-size: 2em;
    border: none;
}

.fab:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,.14),
                0 8px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.28);
}

.fab:focus {
    outline: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    /* Portrait Phone */
    .card {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

The HTML page:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cards Example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/styles.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="card rounded">
            <img src="./res/beach.jpg">
            <p class="title">Rounded Card</p>
            <button class="fab">
                    <i class="fa fa-github-alt"></i>
            </button>
            <p>This card has rounded corners, if that's more your style. I definitely like the subtle rounded corners,
                however rounded cards and normal cards do not go well together.
            </p>
        </div>

        <button class="fab">
                <i class="fa fa-github-alt"></i>
        </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have no idea of the best way to get the FAB centered between then image and the content. I am guessing I should use selectors, but I am unsure of which to use, and how to translate the button so it is centered. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are referring to? You wanted the first `fab` instance to be between the image and the `p` tag correct? I have moved your first instance of `fab` to a new `div` with a class of `button_fab`. This allows us to keep the `button` within your main `div` and we can manipulate the entire button how we like.

You can position the button any way you like. I have given it a `text-align` property and a value of `right`.

```css
I am working on a CSS file to design Cards, similar to Material Design Cards. I have also designed a button similar to a FAB. I wish to combine these two elements, so the card has the FAB on the right side between the image and the card content, but I am not sure how to go about doing this.

Here is the current CSS design: enter image description here

CSS Code:

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|Noto+Serif');

body {
    background: #DDD;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    width: 500px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.card p {
    font-family: 'Noto Serif', serif;
    padding: 2px 16px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.card img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.card p.title {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20pt;
    padding: 2px 16px;
}

.bordered {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.rounded {
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.button_fab {
  text-align: right;
}

.fab {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 11px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18), 
                0px 4px 12px -7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    font-size: 2em;
    border: none;
}

.fab:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0,0,0,.14),
                0 8px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.28);
}

.fab:focus {
    outline: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    /* Portrait Phone */
    .card {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cards Example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/styles.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="card rounded">
            <img src="./res/beach.jpg">
            <div class="button_fab">
              <button class="fab">
                      <i class="fa fa-github-alt"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
            <p class="title">Rounded Card</p>
            <p>This card has rounded corners, if that's more your style. I definitely like the subtle rounded corners,
                however rounded cards and normal cards do not go well together.
            </p>
        </div>

        <button class="fab">
                <i class="fa fa-github-alt"></i>
        </button>
    </body>
</html>
```